# ¿Cómo puedo insertar el precio de la moneda de mi país en mi página web?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress

Tengo una duda con respecto a cómo y de donde sacar el precio de la moneda de mi país.

Lo que estoy haciendo actualmente es una pagina web la cual en el sidebar mostrará el precio de la moneda de mi país transformado a otro. Y lo mismo con el combustible de mi país.

Bueno, el punto es que no sé de donde recoger ese tipo de datos (también con estos datos quisiera hacer una mini gráfica)

Básicamente, esto es lo que quiero hacer en mi página web:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: si vez ahi google dice de donde saca los datos, podrias investigar la pagina, lo mas probable es que tengas que consumir una API, en cuanto a la grafica hay algo llamado chart js con lo que puedes hacer graficas con javascript

Answer (score 2):

veo que eres de México, recuerdo que, para consultar el precio de la moneda MXN puedes usar la [API de Banxico](https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieAPIRest/service/v1/doc/ejemplos)

Para el precio de las gasolinas solo pude encontrar esta [API Gasolinas](https://petrointelligence.com/api.php)

Comment: Disculpa la confusión, soy realmente de Republica Dominicana